# How to update all the copies of a variable used within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to increase the corresponding value, on the click of `+` button, 
but at the same time, on click of any `reset` button, i need to reset all the values to 100.

Currently, i am able to increase the corresponding value on the click of `+` button, but on click of `reset` button, only the values that have not been incremented gets reset to `100`

Basically i need to access a **single value** of `f`(for incrementation) and also **all the values** of `f` together(for resetting)

How do i implement this.
A demo of this problem is available **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hzFTMIfXASNmiHD0TJ6P?p=preview)** in plunkr

**HTML snippet**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <counter-widget startnumber=1 resetter="reset"></counter-widget>
</body>
```

**JS snippet**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.triggerReset = function () {
    $scope.reset = true;
    console.log('reset')
    $timeout(function() { 
      $scope.reset = false; 
    },100)
  }
});
app.directive("counterWidget",function(){
  return{
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
      startnumber: '=',
      resetter: '='
    },
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){
        scope.f =  1; 
        scope.add = function(f){ 
            this.f ++
        }
        scope.reset = function(){
            scope.$parent.triggerReset()
        }
        scope.$watch(function(attr) {
          return scope.resetter
        },
        function(newVal) {
          if (newVal === true) {
            scope.f = 100;
          }
        })

    },
    template:'<li ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3]">'+
             "<button ng-click='add(f)'>+</button>"+
             "{{f}}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+
             "<button ng-click='reset()'>reset</button><br><br>"+
             '</li>'
    }

  })
```

Comment: Please provide plunkar

Comment: it is already provided

Answer (score 1):

ngRepeat creates a new scope for each item, so you get an new `f` for each item. To get access to all values I propose to store the values in an array and bind to this array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/amGSHZqCWsFgjl2bEM98

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.values = []
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      $scope.values.push({f: i});
    }
  }

  $scope.reset();

});
app.directive("counterWidget",function(){
  return{
    scope:{ 
      values: '=',
      reset: '='
    },
    link:function(scope, elem, attr){
        scope.add = function(value){ 
          value.f++;
        }
    },
    template:'<li ng-repeat="item in values">'+
             "<button ng-click='add(item)'>+</button>"+
             "{{item.f}}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+
             "<button ng-click='reset()'>reset all</button><br><br>"+
             '</li>'
    }
  })
```

Comment: so if my ng-repeat looped for 100 times, i needed to make `scope.values` with 100 values..... seriously??

Comment: i am sure there is a much better way to do the same , in a more elegant manner

Comment: @dreamer Why do you care about 100 array elements? The values have to be stored somewhere. Othewise you have 100 value on 100 scope object. where's the difference? See an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/amGSHZqCWsFgjl2bEM98